# search data in table column ignore special characters

Tags: php, mysql

I want to search a string in DB column by ignoring special characters i am working on MYSQL. I have word like

> Manama - Alsalmaniya

and DB i have

> Manama - Al-Salmaniya

can i search this word i only want to search alphabets match.Words are different not same always.
i have tried but its not matching this case my query

```
Select * from mainmwx_deliveryzone_areas where name_en LIKE 'Manama - Alsalmaniya'"
```

its returning me 0 rows found.

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Comment: MYSQL by using PHP

Answer (score 2):

You can use it like this (with replace)

```
Select * 
from mainmwx_deliveryzone_areas 
where replace(name_en,'-','') LIKE replace('Manama - Alsalmaniya','-','')"
```

so you won´t take account of '-'

Comment: I made a mistake, wrote 'raplace' instead of 'replace' in the second one. Can you tell what error it gives you?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT * FROM mainmwx_deliveryzone_areas WHERE MATCH(name_en) AGAINST('Manama - Alsalmaniya' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Comment: Try it again. I was even thinking of error possibility. But a form input of say $name_en = $_POST['name_en']; and replacing the Manama - Alsalmaniya with $name_en must work.